# Unity C# Play an animation once on key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 attack animations named "attacking_1" and "attacking_2", I want to play one at random when player presses "C" key once. I want the animation to continue to play to last frame of it without player needing to hold down the C key.

Here's my code and what's happening is that this code is ran every frame and making my player display both attack animations on one C key press.

What I don't understand is why the if statement is executing many times even tho the player only press the C key once.

```
   if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
    {
        int random = Random.Range(1, 3);
        Debug.Log(random);
        anim.SetBool("attacking_" + random.ToString(), true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Input.GetKey()**"
Checks if a button is pressed down every frame and runs it every frame. What you need is
"**Input.GetKeyDown()**"
Which only runs it the first frame it's pressed down

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I always thought GetKeyDown means holding down the key

Comment: It can be weird at first, but once you start using GetKeyUp, it starts to make sense